# Powershell 2.0 parameter binding exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a batch script, it using powershell to start a detached background process like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32>powershell -c "start-process C:\edgesetup\aria2c.exe -ArgumentList \"-T C:\edgesetup\x64.torrent -d C:\edgesetup\" -RedirectStandardOutput c:\bt.log -RedirectStandardError c:\bt.err -WindowStyle Hidden"
Start-Process : 无法使用指定的命名参数解析参数集。
所在位置 行:1 字符: 14
+ start-process <<<<  C:\edgesetup\aria2c.exe -ArgumentList "-T C:\edgesetup\x64.torrent -d C:\edgesetup" -RedirectStandardOutput c:\bt.log -RedirectStandardError c:\bt.err -WindowStyle Hidden
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

this script is working on windows 10, but fail on windows 7 sp1. I know windows 7 sp1 comes with powershell 2.0, however even [powershell 2.0's documentation](http://adamringenberg.com/powershell2/start-process/) shows that all my arguments should be supported

If I remove the `-WindowStyle Hidden`, it will work on windows 7.

Is this a known bug with powershell 2.0 ？

Comment: Take an extra look at the two parameter sets listed in the linked article - `-WindowStyle` and `-Redirect*` switches are mutually exclusive

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks! I noticed it,  `NoNewWindow` works for me